# no more vs. no longer

Tags: word-usage

what is the difference between 'no more' and 'no longer'?
Can those always replace each other?

A book says,

There were no longer wolves on the island.
There would no longer be too many deer on the island.
There was no more snow.

Answer (score 0):

The two words *can* mean the same thing. But that's not always the case.

> ✔ She died a week ago. She was no more.
> ✘ She died a week ago. She was no longer.
>
> ✘ She died a week ago. She was no more alive.
> ✔ She died a week ago. She was no longer alive.
>
> ✔ She died a week ago. She was no more alive than a rock.
> ✘ She died a week ago. She was no longer alive than a rock.

Note that I may be incorrect about some of the ungrammatical marks (it is my intuition), although the last sentence is definitely ungrammatical. But the main point was to contrast the subtly different sentence constructions.

---

And to use one of your example sentences:

> ✔ There were no longer wolves on the island.
> ✘ There were no longer wolves on the island than the existing two.
>
> ✔ There were no more wolves on the island.
> ✔ There were no more wolves on the island than the existing two.
>
> ✔ One wolf was four-feet long. There were no longer wolves on the island.
> ✔(?) One wolf was four-feet long. There were no more wolves on the island.

*Longer* has two senses: "in existence" and "of greater length". *More* has two senses: "in existence" and "in addition to." In these example sentences, one or the other sense is being used—or it's ambiguous which sense is being used.

Where either *longer* or *more* doesn't mean "in existence," it cannot simply be substituted for the other word. Doing so would change the meaning of the sentence or make it ungrammatical.

*Longer* in the second-last sentence is assumed to mean "of greater length," since *long* applies to length and the two are used next to each other. It would still be grammatical if it meant "in existence," but it would make the combination of the two sentences illogical.

While the last sentence is grammatical, using *more* (meaning either "in existence" or "in addition to") next to *long* would be either illogical or strange.

Comment: Also potentially relevant is the distinction between 'less' and 'fewer'